# OpenGL fullscreen OS X 10.7 Returning Errors

Tags: osx-lion, fullscreen

I'm trying to implement a program that takes a snapshot of your screen & saves the snapshot on your desktop. This program worked fined on 10.6 but when I imported it on 10.7 I get "invalid fullscreen drawable" error on runtime.
I downloaded a sample program from Apple that does exactly the same, using same method etc. & same result...considering Apple's sample program hasn't been updated for a long while (Last revision was in 2008!) do you know if something regarding full screens & OpenGL changed from 10.6 to 10.7.

PS Taking into consideration the fullscreen apps feature in Lion there is a very high possibility something changed, but what exactly is what I'd like to find out.

Comment: BTW OpenGLScreenSnapshot is the name of the sample program downloaded from Apple

Comment: Having the same problem.  I believe it has to do with the way fullscreen has changed.  In lion, when you go to fullscreen, you create another "space" in addition to your usual Spaces.  Previously, when you created the fullscreen context, the fullscreen context was applied over all your spaces.  I believe this behavior has affected the screen capture.  Also, the screen capture option in QuickTime still seems to work.  However, it is now very slow leading me to believe that it uses some other API that doesn't work as efficiently.

Comment: I think spaces are considered as a "Display" you can even set different Desktop Pictures for each space

Comment: That's what I mean.  In Snow Leopard and earlier, spaces were just different desktops on the same display.  Fullscreen filled up the display and remained open, no matter which space was picked.  Now a fullscreen app is only going to be dedicated to one space.  Also, I believe the reason it's failing with your OpenGL code is that you need to call the new API to allocate a new space for your fullscreen mode.